# HDD failing backup advice

Tags: hard-drive, backup, smart

3TB HDD is failing. Failed SMART test, generally behaving weirdly.

Should I try and copy things first to backup drive. Or run the fix tools on Seatools?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Backup immediately. Then you can troubleshoot without worry of data loss.